# ASP.NET MVC ul/li menu

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, menu, html-lists

I'm trying to make a ul/li menu in my ASP.NET MVC application. The menu should have 4 to 5 top menu items and each topmenu item should have a hover/dropdown menu with some submenu items. The finished menu structure should look like a usual ul/li menu with dropdown:

```
<ul>

 <li class="active">
   <a>Topmenu 1</a>
   <ul>
   <li>Submenu1</li>
   <li>Submenu2</li>
   <li>Submenu3</li>
   </ul>
 </li>

  <li class="inactive">
   <a>Topmenu 2</a>
   <ul>
   <li>Submenu4</li>
   <li>Submenu5</li>
   <li>Submenu6</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
  And so on...
</ul>
```

The top menu items should have classes with "active" and "inactive". I solved that problem by making a custom HtmlHelper which generates the topmenu items. That looks like this:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string text,
    string action,
    string controller
)
    {

        var li = new TagBuilder("li");
        var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
        var currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
        var currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        if (string.Equals(currentAction, action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(currentController, controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            li.AddCssClass("tab active");
        }
        else {
            li.AddCssClass("tab inactive");
        }
        li.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(text, action, controller).ToHtmlString();
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(li.ToString());
    }
```

I call the function like this:

```
@Html.MenuItem("Katalog", "Index", "Katalog")
```

This function works very well. Unfortunately the whole topmenu `<li>` item is getting generated. So I have no posibility to place the `<ul>` for the submenuitems somewhere in the topmenu `<li>` tag.

Does someone have an idea how to make a menu like that? Or an idea how I can get my `<ul>` into the topmenu `<li>` tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use something like [Superfish menu](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/). I use it and it's pretty good. The only thing you have to have is the structure of your menu somewhere in your view (`_Layout.cshtml` for example). If you choose to go this way, just create the menu structure (`<ul><li>)` by hand and call the Superfish jQuery plugin. You'll get an awesome menu ready to use no matter how many nesting levels (`<ul>` inside `<li>`) your menu may have. The plugin will handle it nicely.

Sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="superfish.js"></script>

// Create the root <ul> with id = menu... <ul id="menu">
// Call superfish() on the containing ul element.

<script> 

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('ul#menu').superfish(); 
    }); 

</script>
```

You can customize the menu with lots of [options](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#options) like this:

```
<script> 

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('ul#menu').superfish({ 
            delay:       1000,                            // one second delay on mouseout 
            animation:   {opacity:'show',height:'show'},  // fade-in and slide-down animation 
            speed:       'normal',                        // faster animation speed 
            autoArrows:  true,                            // enable generation of arrow mark-up 
            dropShadows: true                             // enable drop shadows 
        }); 
    }); 

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for that great example. I never tohught about generating a menu by js or jquery... Have you already worked with that plugin? Couldn't that cause problems for SEO?

Comment: No problem! I've implemented a menu using this awesome plugin. It's pretty clean... The only thing it adds to the `<ul>`s and `<li>`s is CSS classes to style the menu so that you get a beautiful menu. I can't see any problem regarding SEO.

Comment: I hope this will work for static menus.What if I had dynamic menus? also it might be parent - child along with permissions ?

Comment: @VeeKeyBee this will work for dynamic menus as long as your `<ul>s` `<li>s` are correctly generated.

Comment: i need more help. let me kick off doing my first mvc (trying with mvc 4 razor) . thanks :)